# Indefinite integral with constant

Tags: python

I need to use `python` to get an indefinite integral of `1/(x^4(sqrt(x^2-a^2)))`, where `a>0`.

I know how to use python to integrate, but not when there is a constant.  Just to be clear, the answer needs to be in terms of x and a, because it is indefinite.

Comment: Can you show us the code you use to solve integrals, so that we have code-wise context for the question?

Comment: What are you currently using to integrate with Python? Can you show an example of the code you are using, and what specific part you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

Using [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org), you can compute the symbolic integral for that expression like this:

```
import sympy
# 1/(x^4(sqrt(x^2-a^2))), a > 0
x, a = sympy.symbols('x, a')
exp = 1 / ((x ** 4) * sympy.sqrt(x ** 2 - a ** 2))
exp_int = sympy.integrate(exp, x)
print(exp_int)
```

Which results in:

```
Piecewise((I*sqrt(a**2/x**2 - 1)/(3*a**2*x**2) + 2*I*sqrt(a**2/x**2 - 1)/(3*a**4), Abs(a**2/x**2) > 1), (sqrt(-a**2/x**2 + 1)/(3*a**2*x**2) + 2*sqrt(-a**2/x**2 + 1)/(3*a**4), True))
```

Or displayed with LaTeX:

[image: Integral]